# how can i store a selected radio button in an array?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am making an online examination where questions are coming from the database through php and getting displayed through ajax.I want to get the selected radio button and store it in an array which is not happening because i am not getting the value.Everything else is working  fine only i cant push the radio value in the array.
i can supply the php code if you need to look through the problem
please help

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md" id="mark" onclick="loadNextQues(1)">Mark for Review & Next</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md">Clear Response</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-md" id="save" style="position:absolute;right:20px;bottom:35px" onclick="loadNextQues(0)">Save and Next</button>
<form action="check.php">
  <button type='submit' class="btn btn-info btn-md" id="water" style="visibility:hidden;position:absolute;right:20px;bottom:35px">submit</button>
```

Javascript:

```
 function loadNextQues(flag) {
  quesno++;
  if (flag == 1) {
    //add css to the button for review
  } else {
    //add css for the button as answered
  }
  url = "http://localhost/assignments/load-questions.php?qno=" + quesno;
  $.get(url, function(data, status) {
    response = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(response);
    var quest = "<p>" + response.qno + " " + response.question + "</p>";
    quest += "<form>";
    quest +=
      '<input type="radio" name="op" value=\'' +
      response.opA +
      "'>A." +
      response.opA +
      "<br>";
    quest +=
      '<input type="radio" name="op" value=\'' +
      response.opB +
      "'>B." +
      response.opB +
      "<br>";
    quest +=
      '<input type="radio" name="op" value=\'' +
      response.opC +
      "'>C." +
      response.opC +
      "<br>";
    quest +=
      '<input type="radio" name="op" value=\'' +
      response.opD +
      "'>D." +
      response.opD +
      "<br>";
    quest += "</form>";
    document.getElementById("questBox").innerHTML = quest;
  });

  if (quesno == 15) {
    document.getElementById("mark").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("save").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("water").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
  var myArr = [];
  var Selected = document.querySelectorAll('[name="op"]:checked');
  if (Selected != null) {
    arr.push(Selected.value);
  }
  console.log(arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate through the elements to get their values, also arr is not defined.

Edit to get the intended effect...

```
var arr = new Array();
function loadNextQues(flag) {
  var Selected = document.querySelectorAll('[name="op"]:checked');
  if (Selected != null) {
     Selected.forEach(function(radio) {
        arr.push(radio.value);
     });
  }
  console.log(arr);

  quesno++;
  if (flag == 1) {
    //add css to the button for review
  } else {
    //add css for the button as answered
  }
  url = "http://localhost/assignments/load-questions.php?qno=" + quesno;
  $.get(url, function(data, status) {
    response = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(response);
    var quest = "<p>" + response.qno + " " + response.question + "</p>";
    quest += "<form>";
    quest +=
      '<input type="radio" name="op" value=\'' +
      response.opA +
      "'>A." +
      response.opA +
      "<br>";
    quest +=
      '<input type="radio" name="op" value=\'' +
      response.opB +
      "'>B." +
      response.opB +
      "<br>";
    quest +=
      '<input type="radio" name="op" value=\'' +
      response.opC +
      "'>C." +
      response.opC +
      "<br>";
    quest +=
      '<input type="radio" name="op" value=\'' +
      response.opD +
      "'>D." +
      response.opD +
      "<br>";
    quest += "</form>";
    document.getElementById("questBox").innerHTML = quest;
  });

  if (quesno == 15) {
    document.getElementById("mark").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("save").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("water").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
  var myArr = [];
```

Comment: You are right, Thank you. But when i click save and next, in the console it shows only the last selected radio option in the array and not the selected radio options in the previous questions before that.  Please help  sir/ma'am.

Comment: In that case you need to move `var arr = new Array()` before `loadNextQues` function declaration, and move the code I gave you to the beginning of the function. I'll update my answer to show it

Comment: Thank you so much,you have been a great help. I did what you told me and it works perfectly fine.This works :)

Comment: Can you please help me in one other thing, at the last question there is no save and next button, a submit button appears,all i need to do is onclick the submit button, the array with the previous radio options should include the radio option of last question and move to an another file called check.php.Can you tell me how to do that.Thank you so much for the previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ES6 syntax and the .map() array method. Something like...

var arr = Selected.map(dom => dom.value);

Comment: Can you please be more specific about where should i put this sir and what is dom, actually i am new to Javascript.. thank you

Comment: DOM stands for Document Object Model, in this context, he is referring to the radio input elements you are trying to access. The syntax being used is shorthand for something like this: `var arr = Selected.map(function(radio) { return radio.value; })` map does the job of looping and putting all of your values into one variable.

Comment: Thank you so much.